# What is the correct pitch accent for ううん?

Tags: phonetics, pitch-accent

For ううん to express negation, [Weblio](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%86%E3%81%86%E3%82%93) gives the pitch accent as 【2】, i.e.

ううん 【LHL】

However, (to me) this doesn't sound like how people actually pronounce the word. I've always thought that it sounded like this:

ううん 【HLH】
(Listen [here](https://forvo.com/search/%E3%81%86%E3%81%86%E3%82%93/))

... but I know that is not a proper pitch accent pattern for Japanese. So I'd be interested to hear what a native speaker feels the correct pitch accent pattern for this word is.

Comment: http://ci.nii.ac.jp/lognavi?name=nels&lang=jp&type=pdf&id=ART0009789713

Comment: @snailboat Wow, great article you linked! Thanks. If I have time I will translate some of the key findings and credit you with the answer.

Comment: By the way, the Miyako-shi dialect in Iwate has high-low-high pitch patterns generally. (It's true that these patterns aren't normal in Tokyo jp as well as most other dialects.) The *úùń* case is to me highly reminiscent of the "contradictory pitch contour" in English intonation, where a fall-rise pattern in utterances like "no" or 'quite" give them a particular meaning related to contradiction.

Comment: Do 'no' and 'quite' have fall-rise patterns?

Answer (score 2):

The forvo.com resource you linked has samples provided by native speakers of Japanese, and this is indeed the most common way to pronounce ううん in the context of a negation (I can't say I'm aware of any dialect that pronounces it differently, either). So yes, something like ううん{HLH} is correct.

Answer (score -1):

In my experiences I have heard ううんHLL. Hope this helps!

Comment: are you sure you're not confusing it with うん [HL]